# Retrieving a list of row number from only visible cells

Tags: vba, excel

Let's assume, I have the following table:

```
Toto B June 12pm
Titi A April 11pm
Toto D January 9am
Toto F December 8am
```

I want to extract at each line some data and fill a logsheet. I have done the macro that work for the whole data. However I need to extract only a selection of data now on, let's say only the data having their first column equal to "Toto".

To this end, I am using the Autofilter manually (user friendliness) and then extract only the visible cell meeting the criteria using

```
LastLine = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Export_Range = Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:A" & LastLine).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

To avoid rewriting the macro, I'd like to know if there is a way of outputting a list of row number meeting the criteria. I have search a bit and I haven't been lucky. Any idea?

Comment: There are a few methods. You can use a loop to select which iterate over the Range and selectively copy instances to a log file. You can also try to incorporate an `AutoFilter`. It's difficult to best help you without seeing the entirety of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will list them:

```
Sub ListThem()
    Lastline = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    msg = ""

    For Each r In Range("A2:A" & Lastline).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        msg = msg & r.Row & vbCrLf
    Next r
    MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

This assumes that AutoFilter has already been applied.

Comment: That's a good start. Is it possible to store in a list or vector structur? I am more used to python, so what I am refering is something like that msg[i] = r.Row.

Comment: I replace the for loop you suggested as the one used for my macro. It does work without exporting the list of row number. I feel kind of stupid, not having thought about it earlier. Anyway thanks for helping and pointing me to a fix.